# Можно ли вызывать std::move несколько раз?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Корректен ли подобный код?

```
template <typename smth> int f() {
  smth x;
  smth y = std::move(x);
  smth z = std::move(x); // Снова x, не y

  return y.do_smth();
}
```

Comment: Странно, что вы вызываете `y.do_smth()`. По природе вопроса кажется, что вас больше должно интересовать поведение `z.do_smth()` или `x.do_smth()`, но не `y.do_smth()`.

Comment: @AnT, нет, меня интересует сам `move`. В вызове `y.do_smth()` я заведомо не вижу ничего некорректного. В отличие от аналогичных вызовов для `x` и `z`.

Comment: Ым... Сам `std::move`, как уже много раз говорилось, выполняет лишь невинное приведение типа. Это фактически пустая операция. Сам `std::move` фактически "ничего не делает" и никаких проблем сам по себе создать не может. Всю "работу" в данном примере выполняет тот конструктор `smth`, который будет вызван.

Comment: @AnT, но после него вызывается конструктор перемещения, а источник перемещения уже один раз переместили. Поэтому возникает вопрос, насколько сильно пострадает универсальность кода, если в нём вдруг окажется нечто подобное.

Comment: О том и речь. Происходить будет то, что написано в том конструкторе, который вызовется в этом примере. И, в частности, с объектом-источником произойдет именно то, что написано в том конструкторе, который вызовется в этом примере. А что именно там написано - у вас в вопросе не указано. Кстати, конструктор перемещения будет вызван только в том случае, если он есть у данного класса (не является implicitly deleted).

Comment: @AnT, обновил вопрос, чтобы не было желания привязываться к конкретной реализации. Я как раз об универсальности спрашивал - т. е. либо: а) повторное перемещение - нечто из разряда деструктуризации и присваивания - при хорошей реализации класса будет работать безвредно, либо б) его вызов нежелателен как и вызов любого другого метода после перемещения (при условии, что сам класс не даёт какие-либо дополнительные гарантии).

Comment: @AnT, если оперировать словами из твоего ответа, то получается так: "должна ли джентельменская реализация перемещения поддерживать многократное перемещение из одного и того же значения"?

Comment: Не могу дать однозначного ответа на этот вопрос... С одной стороны, как перемещение так и копирование из уже перемещенного объекта не первый взгляд выглядит как бесполезное/ненамеренное действие, т.е. ошибка. С другой стороны, популярные "джентльменские соглашения" говорят, что перемещенный объект должен сохранить какое-то *валидное* состояние. Копирование любого валидного состояния выглядит как вполне полезная в общем случае операция. А если копирование дозволено, то почему бы не дозволить и перемещение?

Comment: @AnT, интересно. Я даже не задумывался над тем, что его можно копировать после перемещения... Тогда получается, что должно быть можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакого определенного ответа на этот вопрос уровня `language-lawyer` нет. Точнее, с точки зрения абстрактного языка С++ ничего необычного в этом коде нет. В языке С++ существуют разные типы ссылок (включая rvalue-ссылки), категории выражений и правила overload resolution. Если приведенный выше код *корректен* с точки зрения этих правил, то с точки зрения `language-lawyer` в этом коде все в порядке.

А что тут будет происходить во время выполнения - зависит только от авторов класса `smth`. Семантика перемещения - это чисто пользовательская концепция, которая всегда определяется только чисто пользовательским кодом, то есть реализацией класса `smth`. Только от нее будет зависеть "корректность" или "некорректность" этого кода во время выполнения.

Все соглашения и гарантии, используемые при реализации семантики перемещения - это чисто "джентльменские соглашения". Языку С++ эти соглашения не известны и не интересны.

---

И что вообще имеется в виду под "корректен"?

Если первая инициализация физически выполнила перемещение из `x`, то `x` получил какое-то новое "перемещенное" состояние, допускающее как минимум корректную деструкцию `x` и, по "джентльменским соглашениям", возможность присвоить `x` новое значение.

Опять же, вы не обязаны соблюдать последнее соглашение: вы можете полностью запретить какое-либо дальнейшее использование объекта вашего класса после перемещения из него. И даже возможность корректной деструкции "перемещенного" объекта - это тоже не столько требование языка, сколько требование здравого смысла и структуры вашего примера.

Допускает ли "перемещенное" состояние `x` повторное перемещение из `x`? Что при этом получится в `z`? Это определяется только реализацией `smth`. И если реализация такова, что поведение этого кода полностью определено, то формально тут все совершенно корректно.

А устроит ли вас то, что `y` и `z` получат разные состояния и можно ли для такого `y` делать `y.do_smth()` - это определяют авторы класса `smth`. Можно ли делать `x.do_smth()` и `z.do_smth()` - тоже определяют именно они.

В наиболее безопасном случае для класса `smth` семантика перемещения может совпадать с семантикой копирования. Тогда этот код будет вести себя так же, как такой же код без `std::move`.

В другом варианте реализации перемещение из `smth` может приводить объект в обычное "пустое" состояние, как будто объект только что сконструирован конструктором по умолчанию. Тогда [наверное] объект `z` тоже получит такое же "пустое" состояние.

Примеров поведения можно привести бесчисленное множество, но это лишь иллюстрирует тот факт, что происходить будет именно то, что реализовали авторы класса `smth`.

Comment: Ну вызывать на перемещённом объекте что-либо кроме деструктора и присваивания - идея в общем случае плохая. Т. е. `x.do_smth();` - плохо. `z` получает значение из уже перемещённого значения, поэтому он ничем не лучше `х` и `z.do_smth();` - тоже плохая идея. `y` получил своё значение перемещением и содержит хороший объект, поэтому `y.do_smth();` - нормально. Вопрос заключается как раз в вызове `move` на том, откуда уже было перемещение - это нормально как деструктор и присваивание (ну мне это кажется логичным) или плохо как с любыми другими методами?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Стандартные контейнеры, например, не считают так безусловно и категорично, что это "плохая идея". Стандартные контейнеры говорят, что для них после перемещения вы можете вызывать любые методы, которые не имеют pre-conditions. А после того как вы вызвали такие методы и тем самым проверили какие-то pre-conditions, вы уже имеете право вызывать и любые методы, опирающиеся на уже проверенные pre-conditions. И т.д. Так выглядят "джентльменские соглашения" стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: Например, если у вас есть `std::vector<int>` размера 100, вы выполнили перемещение из него, а затем, вызвав метод `size()`, обнаружили, что по какой-то причине ваш вектор теперь имеет "остаточный" размер 3, то вы можете смело использовать его как совершенно валидный `std::vector<int>` размера 3.

Comment: Если вектор так себя ведет, то нужно выбрасывать компилятор/stl - поведение вектора после перемещения описано стандартом:)) Видимо здесь лучше сказать, что можно написать такой оператор перемещения, что он может забирать не весь объект, а  немножко.

Comment: @KoVadim А где именно это описано? Я навскидку вижу лишь общее описание для всех объектов стандартной библиотеки: valid, but unspecified state.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector , 6 конструктор. `After the move, other is guaranteed to be empty().`